# Transition from mysql to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm in the process to learn PDO. I started changing my database connection from this:

```
$dbname = "database1";


mysql_connect(
  ':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
 'root',
 'root'
) or die( mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

to PDO connection:

```
$username = "root";
$password = "root";


try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1', $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

the connection seems to be working but when I try to login on the website (localhost) it doesn't find my username and password.

1. Do I need to change all my mysql_query to PDO since I changed the database connection to PDO?
2. Can I please ask you some reference for a good tutorial to help me during this transition phase? 
   thanks

Comment: [Check out this](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2) for your second question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes you do.
2. Here is a good [PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) and [this one](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)