# mysql query using PDO Syntax

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a query where I am getting the list of databases. This is working fine, but I don't know how to execute the queries here in PDO syntax.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link);

$i = 0;
$cnt = mysql_num_rows($db_list);
while ($i < $cnt) {
    echo '<a href='.$i.'>'.mysql_db_name($db_list, $i).$i.' </a><br>';
    $i++;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transition from mysql to PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312782/transition-from-mysql-to-pdo)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of MySQL databases in PHP using PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766218/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-mysql-databases-in-php-using-pdo)

Comment: In these links, we have only for PDO connection syntax, I need for mysql_list_dbs, mysql_num_nows and mysql_db_name

Answer (score 0):

here sample code with pdo

```
  $user = 'root';

  $pass = 'root';

  $server = 'localhost';

  $dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$server", $user, $pass );

  $dbs = $dbh->query( 'SHOW DATABASES' );

     while( ( $db = $dbs->fetchColumn( 0 ) ) !== false )

      {

        echo $db.'<br>';

      }
```

Comment: Thank You.. could I know where is the $i as I shown in my code

Comment: Could you please help me with passing $i in your code as in my question

Comment: I could but first get me useful